# How can I prevent an Angular 8+ component from executing until an Input property is set and a ViewChild is ready

Tags: angular, mermaid

I've written an Angular component for rendering [mermaid](https://mermaidjs.github.io/) graphs using the [mermaid npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mermaid).

It works as-is (see below), but I would like to find a way of using it without the parent component needing to include an `*ngIf` (to prevent it trying to render when there's no data). I'd like the component itself to be able to decide whether to call `mermaid.render()` or not itself. If the `*ngIf` isn't used then the component's `ngAfterContentInit()` may run when `graphDefinition` is `null`. This causes the `mermaid` library to error.

I could use `ngOnChanges()`, or a property setter, to detect when a value is set but because the component relies on `ViewChild`, I think there's a danger that `ngOnChanges()` or the property setter would execute before the `ViewChild` is ready.

**Question: Can you suggest a way of reliably improving this component so that the `*ngIf` is not required?**

## Usage

Example usage where the graph definition (a string) is provided as an `Observable<string>` from a HTTP call in the parent component:

**parent.component.html**

```html
<mermaid-viewer
    *ngIf="graphDefinition$ | async as graphDefinition"
    [graphDefinition]="graphDefinition"
></mermaid-viewer>
```

## Component

**mermaid-viewer.component.html**

```html
<div #mermaid></div>
```

**mermaid-viewer.component.ts**

```js
import {
    AfterContentInit,
    Component,
    Input,
    ViewChild
} from "@angular/core";
import * as mermaid from "mermaid";

@Component({
    selector: "mermaid-viewer",
    templateUrl: "./mermaid-viewer.component.html"
})
export class MermaidViewerComponent implements AfterContentInit {

    @ViewChild("mermaid", { static: true })
    public mermaidDiv;

    @Input()
    public graphDefinition: string;

    public ngAfterContentInit(): void {

        mermaid.initialize({
            theme: "default"
        });

        const element: any = this.mermaidDiv.nativeElement;
        mermaid.render(
            "graphDiv",
            this.graphDefinition,
            (svgCode, bindFunctions) => {
                element.innerHTML = svgCode;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A complete answer for your question is overly complicated, and it would involve `BehaviourSubject` and operators like `combineLatest`. But I try to give you a hint.

You can combine your `Input` with a setter and a getter, in order to get notified when your input changes:

```
private _graphDefinition: string;
@Input()
public set graphDefinition(value) {
  this._graphDefinition = value;
  // .next() on BehaviourSubject
}
public get graphDefinition() {
  return this._graphDefinition;
}
```

You can do the same thing on the ViewChild, in this case you'll emit just once, when the element view is initialised:

```
private _mermaidDiv;
@ViewChild("mermaid", { static: true })
public set mermaidDiv(value) {
   this._mermaidDiv = value;
   // .next() on another BehaviourSubject
}
public get mermaidDiv() {
  return this._mermaidDiv;
}
```

Then you can use `combineLatest` on the `ngAfterContentInit` (`ngAfterViewInit` would be good too I guess):

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
  // ...
  combineLatest(
     bs1,
     bs2
  ).subscribe(result => {
     // do something with definition + view
     // result[0] => is your graph definition
     // result[1] => is your queried view
  });
  // ...
}
```

Now you can change your `graphDefinition` several times in your parent component, and your configuration will update automatically

Comment: Ah nice, that makes sense. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with this, inspired by the answer from [Cristian Traìna](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58971428/12124) but not using `BehaviourSubject` or `combineLatest`.

The `render()` function will be called twice. The first time only one of either `graphDefinition` or `mermaidDiv` will be available, and it will do nothing. The second time both values will be available, and it will then call `mermaid.render`. I think it's a bit simpler, though perhaps not as elegant - and wouldn't scale well if multiple properties were required.

```js
import {
    Component,
    Input,
    ViewChild
} from "@angular/core";
import * as mermaid from "mermaid";

@Component({
    selector: "mermaid-viewer",
    templateUrl: "./mermaid-viewer.component.html"
})
export class MermaidViewerComponent {

    private hasRendered = false;

    private _mermaidDiv;
    @ViewChild("mermaid", { static: true })
    public set mermaidDiv(value) {
        this._mermaidDiv = value;
        this.render();
    }
    public get mermaidDiv() {
        return this._mermaidDiv;
    }

    private _graphDefinition: string;
    @Input()
    public set graphDefinition(value) {
        this._graphDefinition = value;
        this.render();
    }
    public get graphDefinition() {
        return this._graphDefinition;
    }

    private render() {
        if (this.graphDefinition && this.mermaidDiv) {

            this.hasRendered = true;

            mermaid.initialize({
                theme: "default"
            });

            const element = this.mermaidDiv.nativeElement as HTMLDivElement;
            mermaid.render(
                "graphDiv",
                this.graphDefinition,
                (svgCode, bindFunctions) => {
                    element.innerHTML = svgCode;
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution too. Observables give you a huge power on events, but if you don't forecast any invasive intervention on your component, then also this solution is valid and maintainable